# How to change XML-based Configuration to annotation configuration in Spring?

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations

The class is as following:

```
class ReportControllerBase {
    String reportName = "Report";

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }

    public void setReportName(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

    // ...
}

class AnnualReportController extends ReportControllerBase {
    // ...
}

class SkinCareAnnualReprotController extends AnnualReportController {
    String productName;

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
}
```

And the XML-based configuration is as following:

```
<bean id="annualReportController" class="AnnualReportController">
    <property name="reportName" value="Annual Report"/>
</bean>

<bean id="annualSpecialReportController" class="AnnualReportController">
    <property name="reportName" value="Annual Special Report"/>
</bean>

<bean id="skinCareAnnualReprotController" class="SkinCareAnnualReprotController" parent="annualReportController">
    <property name="productName" value="A famous skin care product"/>
</bean>
```

The Bean ***annualReportController*** and ***annualSpecialReportController*** is the instance of the same Class. And ***skinCareAnnualReprotController*** is inherited from bean ***annualReportController***.

How to implement this configuration in annotation-based configuration in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class ReportConfiguration {
    @Bean public AnnualReportController annualReportController() {
        AnnualReportController annualReportController = new AnnualReportController();
        annualReportController.setReportName("Annual Report");
        return annualReportController;
    }

     @Bean public AnnualReportController annualSpecialReportController() {
        AnnualReportController annualSpecialReportController = new AnnualReportController();
        return withAnnualSpecialReportName(annualSpecialReportController);
    }

     @Bean public SkinCareAnnualReportController skinCareAnnualReportController() {
        SkinCareAnnualReportController skinCareAnnualReportController = new SkinCareAnnualReportController();
        skinCareAnnualReportController.setProductName("A famous skin care product");
        return withAnnualSpecialReportName(skinCareAnnualReportController);
    }

    // in this instance, a helper method is arguably overkill,
    // but I've included it for demonstration
    private <T extends AnnualReportController> T withAnnualSpecialReportName(T report) {
        report.setReportName("Annual Special Report");
        return report;
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [Spring 3.1 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-java-configuration) for more information.

Comment: You're also going to need to add @Qualifier to @Bean so you can inject the various `AnnualReportController`s separately.

Comment: @sourcedelica: you shouldn't need to if the field name is the same as the bean name

Comment: Right - I guess I was assuming that injection was going to be done using @Autowire, not xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still confused on how to implement `skinCareAnnualReprotController` inherit `annualReportController`, not `annualSpecialReportController`.

Comment: I've updated to include the other two beans.  Also, you have some misspellings of 'report', which I've corrected in my answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you! @hertzsprung. In your definition, the `reportName` of `skinCareAnnualReportController` will be **Annual Special Report**?

Comment: Gah, I didn't spot your parent definition, sorry.  Now I understand the crux of your problem!  I'll update my answer again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solves my problem. Also it seems that there is not simple way to implement XML-based bean template in annotation.